# conditional required in material UI textfield

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a function that I call whenever I need to place material ui text fields in my code. The problem I'm running into is how do I add the "required" keyword dynamically using a boolean parameter of whether of not the field is required. What will I add in the if block?

```
function Textfield(name, label, required) {
      if(required){

      }
      else{
        
      }
      return (
        <Grid item>
          <TextField 
            id={name} fullWidth label={label}
            />
        </Grid>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean `<TextField required ...` versus `<TextField ...`?

The `required` prop is a boolean prop, just adding `required` as an attribute is an alias for `require={true}`. Therefore, you can use the regular prop syntax to have it be conditional:

```js
<TextField required={!!required} id={name} fullWidth label={label}/>
```